# Swagger Cancel button should trigger CancellationSource

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, swagger

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class JobController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEventBus _bus;

    public JobController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IEventBus bus)     
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }
    ...

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]JobRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            var command = new JobCommand{ Id = 1, Name = "abc"};
            await _bus.SendCommand(command);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Task was cancelled!");
        }

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = 0 }, null);
    }
}

public class JobCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<JobCommand, bool>
{
    private readonly ILogger<JobCommandHandler> _logger;
    public JobCommandHandler(ILogger<JobCommandHandler> logger)
    {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Handle(JobCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //
        // I was able to reproduce manual cancellation by using this code below

        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.Cancel();
        cancellationToken = cts.Token;

        // how this can be populated sent from the place where I'm issuing command?
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ... 
        // long running task
    }
}
```

My question is:
Do I need to send the `CancellationTokenSource` together with command? If so, how to trigger that from the swagger Cancel button and is it good practice to include `CancellationTokenSource`
to be the property of CommandBase class which every `Command` will extend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cancel all IO and processing if the Http Request which initiated everything got canceled, then, yes. You have to make everything in its path cancellation aware and pass the token through all layers.

You can get a request cancellation token from the HttpContext in the controller from `HttpContext.RequestAborted`.

Now, in your example, I'm not sure what `IEventBus` is. If that is some kind of distributed messaging backend, simply passing a `CancellationToken` will not work, in that case you could send a cancel event to cancel the action I guess.

If it is in-memory eventing only, then it should probably work.